# Please help to download "libsqliteX.so" file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, native

I am developing SQLite Encryption Extension demo for database security.
download demo from "sqlite.org" but I cannot download libsqlite.so file.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Error are give me this line
  System.loadLibrary("sqliteX");

My Logcat give me this error

```
12-05 12:17:09.008 509-509/org.sqlite.app.customsqlite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: org.sqlite.app.customsqlite, PID: 509
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                             at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3846)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sqliteX from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.sqlite.app.customsqlite-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.sqlite.app.customsqlite-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                                                                             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                             at org.sqlite.app.customsqlite.CustomSqlite.run_the_tests(CustomSqlite.java:388)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515
```

Comment: Do you need a build of libsqlite3.so for Android or for your development computer?

Comment: in my project i am not import  and not use libsqlite3.so

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build libsqlite yourself, you might be able use the library shiped with Android.

You find it in the Android 5.1.1 emulator in `/system/lib/libsqlite.so` and can get it using

```
adb pull /system/lib/libsqlite.so
```